# Camel route, unparsed date

Tags: smtp, apache-camel

i'm using camel route that sends emails with smtp.gmail.com 
the URI is something like this

```
 uri="smtps://smtp.gmail.com?to=user@gmail.com&amp;username=user@gmail.com&amp;password=password&amp;debugMode=true&amp;from=user@gmail.com&amp;subject=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}"
```

so i'm expecting to get the current date as Subject , but the date is not parsed and it prints "${date:now:yyyyMMdd}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use the `simple` expression inside the `uri` like that. You'd be better off setting the `subject` and other values in headers.

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:example" />
  <setHeader headerName="subject"><simple>${date:now:yyyyMMdd}</simple></setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="from"><constant>user@gmail.com</constant></setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="to"><constant>user@gmail.com</constant></setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="username"><constant>user@gmail.com</constant></setHeader>
  <setHeader headerName="password"><constant>password</constant></setHeader>
  <to uri="smtps://smtp.gmail.com?debugMode=true" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use your URI inside a RecipientList. So

Instead of:

```
<to uri="smtps://smtp.gmail.com?to=user@gmail.com&amp;username=user@gmail.com&amp;password=password&amp;debugMode=true&amp;from=user@gmail.com&amp;subject=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}"/>
```

Use:

```
<recipientList>
  <simple>smtps://smtp.gmail.com?to=user@gmail.com&amp;username=user@gmail.com&amp;password=password&amp;debugMode=true&amp;from=user@gmail.com&amp;subject=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}</simple>
</recipientList>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Read more here: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html